# Manifest merge failed

Tags: android

I have tried to add recyclerView to android dependencies , but after adding that library it produce this error

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'. > Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(25.3.1) from [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1] AndroidManifest.xml:27:9-31 is also present at [com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.0-alpha1] AndroidManifest.xml:24:9-38 value=(26.0.0-alpha1). Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:25:5-27:34 to override.

I have added it via project structure

Comment: show `manifest.xml`

Comment: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(25.3.1) from [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1] AndroidManifest.xml:27:9-31
 is also present at [com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.0-alpha1] AndroidManifest.xml:24:9-38 value=(26.0.0-alpha1).
 Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to <meta-data> element at AndroidManifest.xml:25:5-27:34 to override.

Comment: Whats the error sar? post your manifest and logs properly sir.

Answer (score 0):

Change your build.gradle(app) to

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "PACKAGE NAME"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.+'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: his error is related to mafiest tag overriding
data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(25.3.1)  how this solves i dont know

Comment: using + is not recommended

Comment: that's work for me thanks. I changed the version of appcompact and recycleview to 26.+ and changed the version of compile sdk to 26 and then error fixed

Comment: @Ehsan.sarshar Using plus is not recommended, you may face problem in future, upto you!

Comment: yes @sector11 you are right but 26.0.0-alpha1 is not a stable version for many dependency and + is also not recommended but when there is a stable buildToolVersion for 26.0.1 then change it to that version in future.

Comment: so if using + is not recommended so what should i do

Comment: as i said before  when ever there will be a stable buildToolVersion for 26.0.1 then change it to that version in future.

Answer (score 0):

This error happens when you include reference to multiple library or module with different version number. So keep all the view library version number in sync

Comment: can u explain more

Comment: Can you post your build.gradle(from app module) file here ?

Answer (score 0):

Please, Make sure all support library version are same:

Add these lines in `build.gradle` at project level not `app/` level

```
ext {
    supportLibrary = '26.0.0' // your support library version goes here
}
```

and then add this to you project level where all android dependencies are declared:

`implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.supportLibrary}"`

And make AndroidManifest similar to this ***if you are using some meta tag.***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="my.supercool.app">


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        **tools:replace="android:value"**
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
</application>

...
</manifest>
```

tools replace actually solves the error message for overriding meta-tag value.